# Does "tödlich verletzt" always mean the same as "getötet"?

Tags: word-choice

When reading the news about e.g. "vier Personen wurden bei dem Unfall tödlich verletzt" it seems to *always* mean that these four people were actually killed in the accident. I'm wondering about the phrasing as "tödlich" AFAIK [means](https://www.dict.cc/?s=t%C3%B6dlich) that something is *potentially* lethal, but not necessarily. So wouldn't it be more accurate if the news were saying "vier Personen wurden bei dem Unfall getötet" instead? Or is "tödlich verletzt" simply a more sensitive expression for "getötet" (at the cost of accuracy)?

Comment: Ist das eine Frage, ob die Begriffe synonym sind - die Überschrift klingt so - (jmd. mit Gift töten wäre eine Form, bei der man m.E. nicht "tödlich verletzt" sagt) oder ist es eine Frage nach Implikation - so klingt der Text? Wenn einige der Unfallopfer erst auf dem Weg ins Krankenhaus starben oder im Krankenhaus 3 Wochen später an den Folgen der Verletzung, dann wurden sie beim Unfall tödlich verletzt aber nicht getötet.

Comment: Ja, ich wollte wissen ob die Begriffe, vor allem von der Presse, synonym verwendet werden, bzw. falls sie nicht synonym sind, was der Unterschied ist. Der zeitliche Aspekt kam mir dabei bisher nicht in den Sinn.

Comment: "tödlich verletzt" means fatally injured. "getötet" means killed.

Comment: That was my understanding so far as well, where "fatally injured" to me means that the person is not (necessarily) dead. But Germans news use the term "tödlich verletzt" to describe that a person has died as a consequence of the injury caused by an accident.

Comment: there might be a difference in time: at the time someone was "getötet", they were dead. at the time someone was "tödlich verletzt", they might have been still alive, but died later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me the phrase "tödlich verletzt" is not the same as "getötet". For example if a plane crashes a native speaker wouldn't say "tödlich verletzt".

Here a [news article](https://orf.at/stories/3150245/). The relevant part is here:

> ...
>   Nacht auf Mittwoch alle 176 an Bord befindlichen Personen getötet.

"Tödlich verletzt" often means killed due to the injuries but the time when the person really died is not defined as opposed to the plane crash.

It might be in the hospital, it might be on the crash site (before the doctor arrived), or it might be in the crash itself.

Comment: I disagree with "is not defined" and "it might be in the crash itself". Because it means "got injured and died due to the injuries after the accident" - so the lethal action was not the accident but the nonfixing of the injuries in time (or even the impossibility to fix them) - so you survive the injury causing action but not the injuries

Comment: The BFU (Bundesstelle für Flugunfalluntersuchung) [defines tödlich verletzt](https://www.bfu-web.de/DE/BFU/Begriffe/Toedlicher%20Verletzung/personen_node.html) as: died within 30 days after the accident, because of the injuries

Comment: @ShegitBrahm look at this [news article](https://www.diepresse.com/5297151/arbeiter-bei-sturz-von-hebebuhne-todlich-verletzt). 18 meters freefall head first. There were no injuries...

Comment: I would translate `tödlich verletzt` to 'mortally wounded'.

Comment: I totally agree The phrase "tödlich verletzt" can be only used if somebody is dead at the moment when the phrase is used..But it remains open whether the person died immediately or some time later as a direct consequence of the injury. The boundary between "immediately killed" and "died some time later" is certainly blurred. However, if somebody survives, frequenty the word "schwer verletzt" or "schwerst verletzt" is used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "tödlich verletzt" is more sensitive and typically used in context of accidents. It is an injury resulted in death. "getötet" is used in case of murder as replacement for "ermordet" in general linguistic usage.

Comment: So, what would be the German expression for a potentially lethal injury that did *not* result in death, i.e. someone barely survived? Is there a concise expression for that?

Comment: @sschuberth - (sehr) schwer verletzt

Comment: lebensbedrohlich verletzt

Comment: "getötet" and "ermordet" are not interchangeable, at the very least not in the legal sense. Someone can be "getötet" by an accident or natural disaster. Someone being "ermordet" implies premeditated intent.
Legally speaking, if you cause an accident, but you didn't intent to kill the person, then that's "Totschlag". Your actions caused someone to die. If you **did** intent to kill the person and you made that decision beforehand and got out of your way to do so, that's "Mord". Many people use these terms synonymously but they are not. So Id say that part of the answer is wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminBasmaci yes, you are right if you speak about the legal situation and the original intention of these words. But like you wrote, many people use these terms synonymously, that was what I meant. Focussed on the "living language"

Comment: Also *lebensgefährlich verletzt*. Also *schwerstverletzt* may be used, but the danger of death is no that obvious then (but also not excluded).

Comment: @BenjaminBasmaci *Ein "Totschlag" liegt vor, wenn eine Person eine andere Person vorsätzlich tötet (§ 212 StGB). Vorsatz (§ 15 StGB) setzt voraus, dass der Täter die Möglichkeit des Taterfolgs (hier: Tod) erkennt und diesen Erfolg entweder will oder doch zumindest "billigt"* (https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/totschlag-in-augsburg-ein-merkwuerdiges-verbrechen-a-1300794.html) If you did not intend it's *fahrlässig*

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That's why I said "Mord" is premeditated. Todschlag is used when a (wanted) killing occurrs in the heat of the moment. If you get into an altercation with someone and it leads to you wanting and succeeding in killing them, then thats "freiwilliger todschlag". If you drive drunk, it might be seen as either "unfreiwilliger Todschlag" or "fahrlässige tötung" (im not a legal expert, not sure about the difference between these two).
However, "Mord" is if you premeditated your act. E.g. you were home alone, planned out to go to your neighbors house 5 hours later and shoot him dead.

Comment: It's not that simple!

Comment: @chrisbergr: do you consider it useful to extend your answer by the comment's content to differentiate between "spoken language" and "legal language"? Also the addings to questions in comments?

Comment: §211 (2) definiert Mord: "Mörder ist, wer

aus Mordlust, zur Befriedigung des Geschlechtstriebs, aus Habgier oder sonst aus niedrigen Beweggründen,
heimtückisch oder grausam oder mit gemeingefährlichen Mitteln oder
um eine andere Straftat zu ermöglichen oder zu verdecken,
einen Menschen tötet." Quelle: dejure.org - dort auch nachzulesen "Totschlag" und "Minder schwerer Fall des Totschlags"